# Using raisebox in longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable

I have small problem while using the `\raisebox` in table environment. In the table, I want to have first three elements (dimer, Atom1, Atom2) out from `multicolumn` using `\raisebox`. Here is the output from my code latex output

[image]

and  the one I want to have.

[image]

My code is as follows,

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape, rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{epsf, graphicx, amsmath, amssymb, subfigure, hyperref, natbib, pdflscape, rotating, multirow,  caption, longtable}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
 \tiny \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8} \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}r*{27}{r}@{}}

\multirow{2}{*}{\raisebox{-\heavyrulewidth}{dimer}}& {\raisebox{-\totalheight}{Atom1}}& {\raisebox{-\totalheight}{Atom1}}& \multicolumn{6}{c}{EXP\textunderscore TOPXD} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{UBDB\textunderscore TOPXD} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{EXP\textunderscore TOPOND} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{OPT\textunderscore TOPOND} \\

 \cmidrule(r){4-9} \cmidrule(r){10-15}\cmidrule(r){16-21}\cmidrule(r){22-27}
%dimer&Atom1&Atom2
& $R_{ab}$ &    d1  & d1 &  $\rho(r)$&  $\nabla^{2}\rho(r)$ & $\epsilon$& $R_{ab}$ &    d1  &d2 &   $\rho(r)$&  $\nabla^{2}\rho(r)$ & $\epsilon$& $R_{ab}$ &    d1&d2 & $\rho(r)$&  $\nabla^{2}\rho(r)$ & $\epsilon$& $R_{ab}$ &    d1  &d2 &   $\rho(r)$&  $\nabla^{2}\rho(r)$ & $\epsilon$\\


 %& $R_{ij}$(BPL) & d1 & d2& $\rho$ & $\Delta$& $\epsilon$ & $R_{ij}$(BPL) & d1 & d2& $\rho$ & $\Delta$& $\epsilon$& $R_{ij}$(BPL) & d1 & d2& $\rho$ & $\Delta$& $\epsilon$& $R_{ij}$(BPL) & d1 & d2& $\rho$ & $\Delta$& $\epsilon$ \\

 \bottomrule

AA1&H(8)&O(10)&0.519&1.198&1.321&0.083&1.75&0.30&2.406&1.102&1.304&0.103&1.713&0.367&2.343&1.020&1.322&0.108&1.49&0.28&2.279&0.976&1.303&0.115&1.61&0.25\\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Plase make your code fully compilable. We are missing the preamble. Having something we can try out without having to add anything makes it a lot easier for us to help

Comment: You might also want to explain exactly what it is you are trying to do. I have no idea what you are using those `\raisebox`'es for

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your response. The reason for using \raisebox to keep the first three elements (dimer, Atom1 and Atom2) out from the center midrule. I have updated the compilable code.

Comment: There are some issues with your `\usepackage{}` line.  `english]` does not belong there.  Also, `normalem` is unknown.  Fixing those, I get compilation, but not the output that you show,

Comment: But dimer and Atom1 and Atom2 does not belong there, they below in the row as `EXP\textunderscore TOPXD` else things looks very un-unified

Comment: Also I do not understand what you are doing with the XX

Comment: You need to use \raisebox{...}[0pt][0pt]{...} to hide the actual location of the text, otherwise the tabular will include it for the whole row.

Comment: Just don't use `\multirow` and type `dimer` and so on in the first row.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code and picture again, sorry for confusions. But what I want to have that dimer, Atom1 and Atom 2 out of multirow. In the content of table, eg: AA1&H(10A)&N(7) corresponds to dimer, Atom1 and Atom which are constant for each row than the numbers. From the R_{ab} to \epsilon should be under midrule.

Comment: The only difference I see between the two pictures is that in the second picture the row beginning with `$R_{ab}$` is shifted to the right. But it is shifted in a strange way, not properly aligning with the columns. So you should use `& & & $R_{ab}$ &    d1 ` etc for that row.

Comment: In the second picture, from the $R_{ab}$ is manually shifted toward right side (by crop tool in MS paint) . My intention by doing to just depict what I the final table should look like.

Comment: are you _really_ using the `epsf` package? why specify `rotating` and `pdflscape` twice?

Comment: But you are talking about dimer and Atom1 (2x), but these are not different in the two pictures.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some `&` in the second row.

I would not use `\multirow` for the first three headers: their level is the same as of “EXP_TOPXD” and the other ones. If you lower them, you make unclear what they refer to: the reader might think they refer to the headers themselves, not to the columns underneath them.

I used also `siunitx` for pretty printing the figures.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape, rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.8}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-4.04pt}
\tiny

\begin{longtable}{
  @{}
  ccc
  *{24}{S[table-format=1.3,round-mode=places,round-precision=3]}
  @{}
}
dimer& Atom1 & Atom1 &
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{EXP\textunderscore TOPXD} &
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{UBDB\textunderscore TOPXD} &
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{EXP\textunderscore TOPOND} &
  \multicolumn{6}{c}{OPT\textunderscore TOPOND} \\

 \cmidrule(lr){4-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-15}\cmidrule(lr){16-21}\cmidrule(l){22-27}
&&&
  {$R_{ab}$} & {d1} & {d2} & {$\rho(r)$} & {$\nabla^{2}\rho(r)$} & {$\epsilon$} &
  {$R_{ab}$} & {d1} & {d2} & {$\rho(r)$} & {$\nabla^{2}\rho(r)$} & {$\epsilon$} &
  {$R_{ab}$} & {d1} & {d2} & {$\rho(r)$} & {$\nabla^{2}\rho(r)$} & {$\epsilon$} &
  {$R_{ab}$} & {d1} & {d2} & {$\rho(r)$} & {$\nabla^{2}\rho(r)$} & {$\epsilon$} \\

\midrule

AA1&H(8)&O(10)&0.519&1.198&1.321&0.083&1.75&0.30&2.406&1.102&1.304&0.103&1.713&0.367&2.343&1.020&1.322&0.108&1.49&0.28&2.279&0.976&1.303&0.115&1.61&0.25\\
AA1&H(8)&O(10)&0.519&1.198&1.321&0.083&1.75&0.30&2.406&1.102&1.304&0.103&1.713&0.367&2.343&1.020&1.322&0.108&1.49&0.28&2.279&0.976&1.303&0.115&1.61&0.25\\
AA1&H(8)&O(10)&0.519&1.198&1.321&0.083&1.75&0.30&2.406&1.102&1.304&0.103&1.713&0.367&2.343&1.020&1.322&0.108&1.49&0.28&2.279&0.976&1.303&0.115&1.61&0.25\\
AA1&H(8)&O(10)&0.519&1.198&1.321&0.083&1.75&0.30&2.406&1.102&1.304&0.103&1.713&0.367&2.343&1.020&1.322&0.108&1.49&0.28&2.279&0.976&1.303&0.115&1.61&0.25\\

\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, take note that `epsf` has been deprecated for more than twenty years and exists only for compatibility with newer documents. I've removed most packages not needed for this particular example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I works smoothly. From  next time onward I'll use siunitx, its much better than \multirow.